# Magento 'Mage_Ecommerceteam_Cloudzoom'

Tags: php, magento-1.7

i create magento wbsite and then the site is upload online then error occur that site is run proper in local server

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Ecommerceteam_Cloudzoom_Helper_Data' not found in /home/ebiz/public_html/prjt/adamas/app/Mage.php on line 546
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are problem into the zooming extension into your theme please install this extension.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cueblocks-zoom.html